# How to add values against each jquery emoticons

Tags: jquery, html, emoticons

I have a feedback form and for that i am using JQuery Feedback Library .
Each smiley contains some value For example 'angry', 'disappointed', 'meh', 'happy', 'laughing'

there is some value for each smiley that is

```
angry = unsatisfactory
laughing = excellent
```

this is all working fine but what i want is to show value on form
for example.

on bottom of first smiley it displays Unsatisfactory

on bottom of second smiley it displays Bad

on bottom of fifth smiley it displays excellent.

```js
var emotionsArray = ['angry', 'disappointed', 'meh', 'happy', 'laughing'];

$('.SmileyRating').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  $(this).emotionsRating({
    emotionSize: 35,
    inputName: name,
    bgEmotion: 'happy',
    emotions: emotionsArray,
    color: '#FF0066', //the color must be expressed with a css code
    disabled: false, //set if the rating can be changed or not, default is falseS ME
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Emoji-Rating-Plugin-jQuery-Emotion-Ratings/emotion-ratings.js"></script>

<div class="w3layouts_main wrap">
  <h1 class="agile_head text-center" style="color:lime">Feedback</h1>
  <form action="#" method="post" class="agile_form">
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">1. Quality of Service. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with our Service?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="QualityOfService">
       </span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">2. Quality of Food. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with our Food?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="QualityOfFood">
        </span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">3. Cleanliness of Lounge. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with Marhaba Lounge Cleaning?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="CleanlinessOfLounge">
            </span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">4. Friendliness of Staff </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with our Staff?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="FriendlinessOfStaff">
            </span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">5. Overall experience. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with Marhaba Lounge?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="OverAllExperience">
             
            </span>
    <br />
    <h3 style="color: white; font-size: large">Valuable Suggestions.</h3>
    <textarea placeholder="Additional comments" class="w3l_summary" name="Comments"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="agileinfo" style=" background-color:white; color: #e60053 " onmouseover=" this.style.backgroundColor = '#e60053', this.style.color = 'white' " onmouseout="    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white',   this.style.color = '#e60053'"
    />

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add function emotionsRating  to the snippet I made you

Comment: That is a jQuery plugin [https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Emoji-Rating-Plugin-jQuery-Emotion-Ratings/](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Emoji-Rating-Plugin-jQuery-Emotion-Ratings/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of behaviour you'd like ?
(Like in your snippet, I don't know why only the last shows correctly the icons, but tell me anwyay…)

```js
var emotionsArray = ['angry', 'disappointed', 'meh', 'happy', 'laughing'];

$('.SmileyRating').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  $(this).emotionsRating({
    emotionSize: 35,
    inputName: name,
    bgEmotion: 'happy',
    emotions: emotionsArray,
    color: '#FF0066', //the color must be expressed with a css code
    disabled: false, //set if the rating can be changed or not, default is false
  });
});


$('.emotion-style').on('click', function(e) {
  value = $(this).data('index');
  // Remove the current .emotion-text, if exists
  $(this).closest('.emotion-container').find('.emotion-text').remove();
  // Add the emotion-text as a span
  $(this).closest('.emotion-container').append('<span class="emotion-text">' + emotionsArray[value] + '</span>');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
}

.agileinfo {
  background-color: white;
  color: #e60053
}

.agileinfo:hover {
  background-color: #e60053;
  color: white;
}

/* Added the below to stylize the class added by the JS code */
.emotion-text{
  margin: 0 16px;
  color: #e60053
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Emoji-Rating-Plugin-jQuery-Emotion-Ratings/emotion-ratings.js"></script>

<div class="w3layouts_main wrap">
  <h1 class="agile_head text-center" style="color:lime">Feedback</h1>
  <form action="#" method="post" class="agile_form">
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">1. Quality of Service. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with our Service?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="QualityOfService"></span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">2. Quality of Food. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with our Food?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="QualityOfFood"></span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">3. Cleanliness of Lounge. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with Marhaba Lounge Cleaning?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="CleanlinessOfLounge"></span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">4. Friendliness of Staff </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with our Staff?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="FriendlinessOfStaff"></span>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: white; font-size: large">5. Overall experience. </h1>
    <h2 style="color : #0086ce">How satisfied were you with Marhaba Lounge?</h2>
    <span class="SmileyRating" data-name="OverAllExperience"></span>
    <br />
    <h3 style="color: white; font-size: large">Valuable Suggestions.</h3>
    <textarea placeholder="Additional comments" class="w3l_summary" name="Comments"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="agileinfo" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what if i want to show it on right corner instead of left

Comment: @Faizan I edited. Better targetting with JS code, added a class, then you can stylize using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$('.emotion-style').on('click', function(e) {
    var trigger = $(this),
        value = trigger.data('index');

    $('.emotion-container').append('<span>'+emotionsArray[value]+'</span>');

});
```

I used the example code on the [plugin page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Emoji-Rating-Plugin-jQuery-Emotion-Ratings/), class names may be different from yours.

In addition you can add a `.on('hover')` event listener to show the value they are about to click.